# Übersetzung von 'Is it a her or a him?'

Tags: personal-pronoun

Es ist mir leider nicht gelungen eine gute Übersetzung ins Deutsche von der Frage nach dem Geschlecht eines Tieres zu finden: 'Is it a her or a him?'

Behält man dabei die Artikel (wie im Englischen) oder sagt man 'Ist das er oder sie?'

Comment: It is a good idea to have a complete question in the body of the text. I made an edit. Please revert, if you disagree.

Comment: Just a curious question of mine, but wouldn't you ask "it is a she or a he" in English?

Comment: it can be both. that a know of. if only i had  typed your variant  somewhere i would.ve not asked this question here. it turns out there are plenty of good translation examples of "a she/ a he".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bei Tieren sagt man: "Ist es ein Männchen oder ein Weibchen?"

Comment: Das ist auch möglich, aber mehr bei z.B. Meerschweinchen und Hamstern als z.B. bei Hunden. Als Übersetzung von "Is it a her or a him?" wäre mir das zu frei.

Comment: Vielleicht variiert das regional. Mir ist es durchaus auch bei Hunden oder Katzen geläufig. Die wörtliche Übersetzung "Ist es ein Er oder eine Sie?" kenne ich hingegen gar nicht und hätte sie spontan als Anglizismus klassifiziert.

Answer (score 6):

> "Ist es ein Er oder eine Sie?"

ist die übliche Formulierung. Dabei gibt es also einen Unterschied zum Englischen - im Deutschen wird nur der Nominativ benutzt, im Englischen ist es entweder das *subject pronoun* ("[a he or a she](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/214674/is-it-a-he-or-a-she-question-correctness)") oder das *object pronoun* ("a him or a her") *(Danke @jonathan.scholbach)*. In beiden Sprachen wird der unbestimmte Artikel benutzt.

Aus der Verwendung des Artikels folgt nebenbei auch, dass die Pronomen "er" und "sie" hier substantivisch gebraucht werden, deshalb werden sie groß geschrieben.

Comment: Ist richtig und doch auch kurios: es = er oder sie ;-)

Comment: Habe ich im Wirklichen Leben (TM) auf Tiere bezogen noch nie so gehört.